# Insert without "IN" or "EXISTS"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called UserGroups which consists of "`USER_ID`" which is a primary key in the "`User Table`" and "`GROUP_ID`" which is a primary key in the "`Group Table`"

```
___________________
|User_ID | Group_ID|
```

- A user can belong to many groups

However, my query is to try and put a user (with the id "1") into all groups that the user is not already in. The rule is not to use the "IN" or "Exists" clause.

I tried doing an insert statement but I could not think of anyway of inserting without using an " IN " or " EXISTS " clause.

```
INSERT into UserGroups
VALUES(1,*)
```

Comment: `mysql`, `sql-server`, and `plsql` are all vendor-specific and mutually exclusive. Which database are you actually using?

Comment: mysql is the database I'm using. I Apologise @Allan

Answer (score 2):

A solution for SQL Server

```
INSERT INTO UserGroups (UserID, GroupID)
SELECT 1, GroupID
FROM Groups
EXCEPT
SELECT UserID, GroupID
FROM UserGroups
```

I think for Oracle

```
INSERT INTO UserGroups (UserID, GroupID)
SELECT 1, GroupID
FROM Groups
MINUS
SELECT UserID, GroupID
FROM UserGroups
```

And MySQL

```
INSERT INTO UserGroups (UserID, GroupID)
SELECT 1, GroupID
FROM Groups
WHERE GroupID NOT IN (SELECT GroupID FROM UserGroups WHERE UserID = 1)
```

Without `IN`

```
INSERT INTO UserGroups (UserID, GroupID)
SELECT 1, GroupID
FROM Groups
LEFT JOIN UserGroups 
ON UserGroups.GroupID = Groups.GroupID
AND UserGroups.UserID = 1
WHERE UserGroup.GroupID IS NULL
```